# Suppose there exist exactly $n$ circles with non-zero radius in the plane tangent to all the three lines,then the possible values of $n$ is/are

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Three distinct lines are drawn in a plane.Suppose there exist exactly $n$ circles with non-zero radius in the plane tangent to all the three lines,then the possible values of $n$ is/are
$(A)0\hspace{1cm}(B)1\hspace{1cm}(C)2\hspace{1cm}(D)4$

---

This is multiple correct answer type question.I could imagine only one case when the three lines are making a triangle and a circle is inscribed in that triangle,touching the three lines tangentially.So i guessed answer is $(B)$,but the book says answer is $(A),(C),(D)$.I am confused how is it so?Please help me.

Comment: Hint: suppose two or more of the lines are parallel.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Excircles.html

Comment: I considered this case too,but still could not imagine 0,2,4 circles.

Comment: Well...is there any circle tangent to $y=-1$,$y=0$,$y=1$?

Comment: No,ok this justifies $(A)$ option.

Comment: Ok, so now suppose only two of the lines are parallel.

Comment: But why is option $(B)$ incorrect?

Comment: For the reason that @mathlove suggests.

Comment: Ok,Two parallel lines and an intersecting lines.In this case,2 circles are tangent to all the three lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three cases are  A, C and D because as you see  in the pictures below. Case B is incorrect because as you said above, having three intersecting lines will generate one circle inbetween, but also three circles are left as you can see in case of 4 circles. [image]
[image]
[image]